# What is the closest thing to Windows notepad on the Mac?

Tags: macos, software-rec, text-editing

What is the closest thing to Windows notepad on the Mac?

I'm using Leopard.

Comment: I've been looking for this exact same thing for a long time, but no one seems to know any tool like this. I don't need multi-file editing, rich text, HTML or code editing, colors or anything at all. I just want a plain Notepad-like app that will open any file without fuss and show it in any font I choose. There seems to be no such thing.

Comment: There's always vi

Answer (score 73, accepted):

[TextEdit](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2523) is included with OS X.

You can change it to Plain Text (`Format > Make Plain Text`) for non-RTF text editing, or make Plain Text the default (`Preferences > Format`).

Comment: TextEdit is even better—it's like Notepad and WordPad combined into one program.

Comment: Being better than Notepad is a pretty low bar. ;-P

Comment: Btw, TextEdit is built in to OS X, including Leopard.  It's located in the Applications folder.

Comment: One thing I miss is being able to open ANY file inside windows notepad.  Like I could take a .gif file if I wanted and see the first 2 chars of that GIF file if I opened it in notepad.  In TextEdit it tells me that the file is not a supported type.

Comment: I guess I can use commands like more or less to see this but being able to edit it with a GUI is desirable for me for some reason.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I just opened a `.gif` and a `.jpg` with TextEdit. Works via dragging onto the Dock icon, opening it via Right-Click > Open With... and TextEdit > File > Open...

Comment: To open most files, just add the extension .txt to them. Also, if you need to work closer to the nuts and bolts, you'll want to: 
1) Set "TextEdit > Preferences > New Document > Format" to "Plain text" and 2) Set "TextEdit > Preferences > Open and Save > When Opening a File:" to "Ignore rich text commands in HTML files"

Comment: Try a zip file dragging it onto the icon.  Even if you rename it to .txt.  The document Date.zip.txt could not be opened.  THe file is not in the right format.  The file might be corrupted, truncated, or in a different format than you expect.

Comment: In that case I do recommend TextWrangler. While TextEdit is a decent editor, it's pretty basic and focused more on word processing than anything else.

Comment: replace all function? replace all at the same time for all opened files (tabs) in this app?

Comment: TextEdit can corrupt files by adding smart quotes when not required. It's not as barebones as notepad

Comment: Agree with @Gi0rgi0s. TextEdit always convert " to “. It make scripts broken.

Answer (score 5):

If you want simple text editing, use TextEdit.

For code editing, one of the best choices is [TextMate](http://macromates.com/).

Comment: jEdit. Supports Elastic Tabstops, which you all must adopt.

Comment: For code editing, the best light-weight text editor comes today is Sublime Text.

Answer (score 4):

As already stated, TextEdit is the notepad of OS X (although a more powerful notepad that is). For more advanced stuff, TextMate (already recommended) is very nice. A nice free and famous alternative is Bare Bones's [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/TextWrangler/).

You can do pretty much with either.

Comment: Unfortunately they have discontinued TextWrangler. BBEdit includes the same features in a free mode.

Answer (score 2):

FYI - you can default TextEdit to plain text when it opens:

- Goto preferences
- Under Format, click on "Plain Text"

http://support.apple.com/kb/TA20406

Can't believe it took me this long to figure that out

Answer (score 0):

Editra for Mac is simple, free, open-source, highly configurable. All in all, it's my favorite Windows Notepad replacement for the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Textmate](https://macromates.com/), that works out-of-the-box just like notepad, plus you can activate (if you wish) more and more functions.